# Role based authorization failed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

this is a admin controller:

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
    public class AdminManagerController : Controller
    {


        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult MakeUserLecturer()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

This user belong to "admin" role as you can see in the db:
[role table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTb9m.png)

This user belong to "admin" role: [userRoles table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9j0sp.png)

And when i enter to this function with the admin user, i get login page that means this user is not admin... but this user is admin...
Why its dont work? and how should i fix it?

Comment: I suggest you debug by looking at all the claims in the identity after login, you should be able to find the admin role there.

Comment: I dont use claims. When i register a user, i do userMeneger.addToRoleAsync(user,roleName).

Comment: Of course you use claims, roles are translated to claims. After you login, have a look at ClaimsPrincipal.Claims. ClaimsPrincipal is HttpContext.User.

Comment: Where should i have a look? i am new in identity framework so i did not find ClaimsPrincipal.Claims . can u explain more where i need to look please?

Comment: I just explained. Look at the HttpContext.User property, it is of type ClaimsPrincipal. Then look at its Claims property, there you will find all the claims, including the roles, associated to the current user.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal?view=netframework-4.8.

Comment: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier: 7f972327-cfa0-40a0-9431-f16c3497f9ce
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name: 209837311
AspNet.Identity.SecurityStamp: NAI76YVNQUKBP65VZHYILUEEJN66MMOB
http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role: admin
amr: pwd
this is the output. i see admin is the role of this user

Comment: OK, so that part is ok.